# Avoid nesting promises.eslint(promise/no-nesting)

Tags: promise, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, eslint

My goal is to write a Cloud Functions on `auth.user` creation.

This function should create the `users/user` if it doesn't already exist.
To create a user I first need to create an `entities/entity`, `entity` that I need to create a `user`

Here is my solution, but eslint is complaining that I should avoid nesting promises. How can I refactor to make it more clean?

```
exports.createUserNode = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

    return getUser(user.email)
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            if (querySnapshot.empty) {
                return createEntity("new Entity").then((docRef) => {
                    var entity = docRef.get();       
                    return db.collection('/users').add({
                            email: user.email,
                            uid: user.uid,
                            entities: [{ uid: entity.data().id, name: entity.data().name }]
                        })
                    })
            } else { // user already exist
                return null;
            }
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
            return console.log("Error creating new user: ", error);
        });
});

function getUser(email) {
    return db.collection('/users').where("email", "==", email).limit(1).get();
}

function createEntity(name) {
    return db.collection('/entities').add({
        name: name
    })
}
```

Comment: You have a then() nested inside another then(), which eslint is configured to complain about.  It's considered to be a bad programming practice.